# Unset focus from WindowsForms TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have simple WinForm app to learn C#.

It contains TextBox and when I started my app all text in this TextBox is selected by default.

Which property I should set to make the text unselected?
[image]

Comment: Do you want the caret at the end of the text or no selection at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the TagStop property to false or you set the tagindex to another number when you initialize the Form.

Answer (score 1):

Set your `SelectionStart` to 0.

```
text1.SelectionStart = 0;
```